# How to subtract Time in Excel VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, datetime, time

How do I subtract Time in Excel VBA? 
I tried to subtract these two values, but I'm getting this value "2.1527777777778E-02" instead. What does this mean?

Timein = 12/7/16 12:00:00 AM

Timeout = 12/7/16 12:30:00 AM

Here's a sample of my code. Thanks in advance.

```
Dim Total as Double
Dim Timein as Date
Dim Timeout as Date

Total = TimeValue(Timeout) - TimeValue(Timein)
'Result Total=2.1527777777778E-02
```

Comment: Excel keeps track of dates and times in days. So 2.1527777777778E-02 means 2.1527777777778E-02th of a day.

Comment: You can also use the [DateDiff](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251417.aspx) function to calculate intervals between two dates.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the [DateDiff](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/datediff.php) Function to get the difference in year/days/seconds or whatever.

Here the example for minutes.

```
Dim Timein As Date
Dim Timeout As Date

Timein = "12/7/16 12:00:00 AM"
Timeout = "12/7/16 12:30:00 AM"
Debug.Print DateDiff("n", Timein, Timeout)
```

Output:

```
30
```

> Interval  Explanation
>
> yyyy  Year
>
> q Quarter
>
> m Month
>
> y Day of year
>
> d Day
>
> w Weekday
>
> ww    Week
>
> h Hour
>
> n Minute
>
> s Second

Comment: If an hours:minutes:seconds format is useful, then use Format((DateDiff("s", Timein, Timeout))/86400, "hh:mm:ss") which returns string 00:30:00.

Answer (score 3):

What you have done is perfectly correct, as can be seen by the following code:

```
Sub test()
    Dim Total As Double
    Dim Timein As Date
    Dim Timeout As Date
    Timein = CDate(Range("A1").Value)
    Timeout = CDate(Range("A2").Value)

    Total = TimeValue(Timeout) - TimeValue(Timein)

    Debug.Print Total
    Debug.Print Format(Total, "hh:mm:ss")

    Range("A3").NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss"
    Range("A3").Value = Total

    Debug.Print "Number of hours = " & Total * 24
End Sub
```

As mentioned by vacip in a comment, Date/Time variables are stored in VBA in "days" so, for example, `Now` for me is the number `42867.7513310185`.

Answer (score 3):

`2.1527777777778E-02` is using a method of displaying a value called Scientific Notation. In your case, it means `2.1527777777778` times `10` to the power of `-2`. Or you could think of the `E-02` part as meaning shift the decimal point two places to the left (left because it's negative).
So: `0.021527777777778`.

Excel treats time (both dates and times of day) as whole days so half a day (12 hours) would be represented as `0.5`.

So the result itself represents the decimal fraction of an entire day, if you want this in minutes for example, you would multiply the value by `1440` (24hr x 60min make a day) which would give you `31`mins.

In your example, you're finding the difference between `12:00` and `12:30` so you should actually be getting a result of `2.08333333333333E-02` which if multiplied by `1440` would give you `30`mins.

Excel gives you tools to find the difference between two points in time though that take all that complex math(s) away - `DateDiff` and @holger has given you everything you need there to write your own code.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined the total as double, which returns you number. you need to dim the total as date so that returns you a time.

```
Dim Total as Date
Dim Timein as Date
Dim Timeout as Date

Total = TimeValue(Timeout) - TimeValue(Timein)
```

Comment: I need to define Total As Double because I need to get the Total Hours which is Total = (Total / 1) * 24

Answer (score -1):

Multiply 2.1527777777778E-02 x 24 x 60 x 60 = 1860 seconds
for 24 hours x 60 minutes x 60 seconds

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).